Magento 2 custom API working for Bearer Token and not working for OAuth1.0
I have created a custom API endpoint to retrieve data from a custom table in magento 2.
Webapi.xml file content
<route url="/V1/bs-customer-price-information/:email/:website_id" method="GET">
    <service class="BS\KoRPricing\Api\KoRPricingRepositoryInterface" method="getPriceListByCustomerAndWebsite"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Magento_Catalog::products"/>
    </resources>
</route>

This endpoint giving result with Bearer Token.

If I tried to access the same API endpoint using OAuth1.0 i am getting an error.

And with the same time i can access magento default API endpoints using OAuth1.0.
While developing this custom api end point is there anything i messed up with? Please advice
